# CakePHP syntax to retrieve associated fields from $Auth

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

CakePHP 3.7.
Here my 'Users' table:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Customers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT'
        ]);
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        ... 
    }

    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['customer_id'], 'Customers'));

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

and 'Customers' table:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Entity\Customer;
use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\ORM\Association\HasMany;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class CustomersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('customers');
        $this->setDisplayField('company_name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->hasMany('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
        ]);
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here the 'login' method in UsersController:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect.'));
    }
}
```

Well, now I want to retrieve in both controllers and templates the associated fields through `customer_id`, example:

```
$this->Auth->user('customer_id')); // <--- WORKS
$this->Auth->user('Customers.company_name')); // <--- ???
```

I don't understand what syntax I have to use to "navigate" via foreign key (`customer_id`) in order to read the other fields in the `Customers` table.

Of course I can use a workaround:

1. retrieve the 'customer_id' value (like above)
2. create a query on 'Customers' filtering for that id
3. read the other fields

But I guess this isn't the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [customize your Auth finder query](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query) to include containing the customer record.

Beware, though, that the entire Auth component is deprecated, and will be replaced in version 4 with the separate [authentication](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/index.html) and [authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/1/en/index.html) middleware plugins.